# JavaFX disable button

Tags: button, javafx

I'm writing a program in netbeans with javaFX
The view has several buttons in it with some bad buttons(like bombs is minesweeper), I'm trying to freeze the program when a bad button is pushed but i don't find how to do it

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say `Freeze the program`? Do you want to `freeze the button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various solutions to your problem. 2 among them are simply ignoring the action event or disabling the buttons like this:

```
public class ButtonAction extends Application {

    final BooleanProperty buttonActionProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();

        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox( "Enabled");
        checkBox.setSelected(true);

        // solution 1: check if action is allowed and process it or not
        buttonActionProperty.bind( checkBox.selectedProperty());

        Button button = new Button( "Click Me");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            if( buttonActionProperty.get()) {
                System.out.println( "Allowed, processing action");
            } else {
                System.out.println( "Not allowed, no action");
            }
        });

        // solution 2: remove comments to activate the code
        // button.disableProperty().bind(buttonActionProperty.not());

        root.getChildren().addAll(checkBox, button);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 200));
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a ROOT typed event filter that consumes all kind of events (mouse, keyboard etc.)

```
btnThatHasHiddenMine.setOnAction(( ActionEvent event ) ->
{
    System.out.println("Ohh no! You just stepped over the mine!");
    getGameboardPane().addEventFilter( EventType.ROOT, Event::consume );
});
```

Add the filter to your GameboardPane only, since we don't want to freeze other part of the app.